# conda build works but not conda install : conflicts in environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, setuptools, conda-build

I am trying to build a python package for a python library with a C++ back-end :
https://gitlab.com/cytosim/cytosim/-/tree/pybind

I managed to have a working package for pip that compiles and installs well, provided the adequate libraries are install in the system (`pip3 install cytosim` works).

Now I am making the conda package with the meta.yaml file shown below.

In a clean virtual machine (Ubuntu 22.04) with conda installed and updated, I can build the package with `conda build -c conda-forge .` without issue.

However when I want to actually install it with `conda install -c local cytosim`, I get an error... That depends on the environment.

In a clean env `myenv` I get :

> Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: -
> Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
> This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
> failed
> ResolvePackageNotFound:
>
> - libstdcxx-ng[version='>=12']

**I tried to add `libstdcxx-ng>=12` to the requirements (in build, host, run), to no avail.**

In `base` I have another error message :

> Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: |
> Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
> This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
> failed
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
> Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
>
> - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
> - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
>   Your installed version is: 2.35

Any clue on what I could do ?

Here is the meta.yaml file :

```
{% set name = "cytosim" %}
{% set version = "0.0.10" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  url: "https://pypi.io/packages/source/{{ name[0] }}/{{ name }}/{{ name }}-{{ version }}.tar.gz"

build:
  number: 0
  script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv"

requirements:
  build:
    - cmake>=3.14
    - make 
    - {{compiler('cxx')}}
    - libblas
    - liblapack
    - pybind11
  host:
    - pip
    - python
  run:
    - python
```